# Github API, get apps with access to protected branch, getting 404

Tags: jwt, http-status-code-404, github-api

I am using the github /repos api. I am specifically trying to find which apps have access to the protected branch in github (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-apps-with-access-to-the-protected-branch)

The url should basically be `/repos/REPONAME/branches/BRANCH/protection/restrictions/apps`

My headers look like this:

```
headers = {
        'Authorization': 'token ' + token,
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json",
    }
```

I am using a token from a github app I have installed on that repo. I know that app has access and that the pem is correct because when I hit the endpoint: `/branches/BRANCH/protection`,  I get a valid response.

I will mention I am attempting this on a forked repo. Thanks!